# Multiple '=' in one line SQL where clause

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I was wondering what happens if I combine multiple 'and' in a where clause of a query into 1 line. For example:

**Instead of this**,

```
   select *
   from t1, t2, t3, t4
   where t1.id=t2.id
     and t2.id=t3.id
     and t3.id=t4.id
```

**where clause becomes like this:**

```
where t1.id=t2.id=t3.id=t4.id
```

I tried running the shortcut, code successfully compiled but the output is as if it omits the where clause all together. Im newbie to SQL so was just wondering why doesn't it work. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's invalid syntax.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I also noticed that code successfully compiled. However, the output is as if it omits the where clause

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why SQL doesn't allow this but even if it did it may not be a good idea to use it because it could lead do misunderstandings.

Please consider this C++ code:

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 3;
    int z = 3;

    if( x == y == z )
    {
        return 111;
    }
    return 7;
}
```

It happens that `main` will return 7 because of precedence of operations and how c++ works.

I think it's for the best that we need to keep things separate in SQL.